# "pronounciation" tag should be "pronunciation" instead

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The correct noun for "to pronounce" is "pronunciation" (without one 'O'):

http://www.beedictionary.com/common-errors/pronounciation_vs_pronunciation

So how would we rename the tag? Or would someone at least create a tag synonym for it?

Comment: Fixed. It's just a spelling error. No need to create a synonym; The text completion will help authors use the correct spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pronounciation doesn't exist in english, so just replace it with Pronunciation. Using the first might lead to people learning words improperly.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should rename it to `pronunciation`, and create a tag synonym for `pronounciation` leading to `pronunciation`.